Android studio Ladybug 2024.2.1| Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.6.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
I updated android studio to Android Studio Ladybug 2024.2.1.  but none of my projects can run in Android studio Ladybug 2024.2.1.  I ended up getting this error.
Here is my gradle:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.6.3" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

include ":app"


Looks like the version 7.6.3 of the Android Gradle Plugin (Used by com.android.application in the gradle file) doesn't exist.
Here is a list of release versions of the Android Gradle Plugin: https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases.
The last 7.x release was: 7.4.2. You could try entering this version and check whether that fixes the build.
I don't know about compatibility between certain Flutter versions and the Android Gradle Plugin. You might wanna check whether the Flutter version you're using is compatible with the Android Gradle Plugin version.
Here is general compatibility information for Android Studio and the Android Gradle Plugin: https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility.

The error message in general tells you, that the version 7.6.3 of the com.android.application Gradle plugin couldn't be loaded. There can be many reasons for this – for example a faulty internet connection.
This question has a lot of different answers that fix different causes of this error. You could also check these, if changing the version doesn't work: Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.2, Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources.
